# Android bluetooth permission granted automatically

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions

I'm developing an APP using jetpack compose. On the onboarding screen I need to ask user for permission, but only when I ask for fine location permission, there is dialog popup. When I ask for BLUETOOTH, nothing happened. I debug my code, print log information.
Here is my button for requesting permission

```kotlin
Button(onClick = {
//            navController.navigate(Screen.OnboardingLocationScreen.route)
            Log.d("bluetooth permission", "${activity.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED}")
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                arrayOf(
                    android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                    android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                    android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                ),
                3
            )
        }
```

It turns out without asking permission, Bluetooth is already granted. I find log information is true and I receive message from onRequestPermissionsResult() without grant permission on the app.

```kotlin
@Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == 3) {
            Log.d("permission","bluetooth")
    }
```

Here is log information

```
D/bluetooth permission: true
D/permission: bluetooth
```

I'm using API29 now.

Comment: Maybe bluetooth permission has actually been granted. You can confirm this by going into app information on your phone and verifying which permissions are granted/denied

Comment: But I uninstall app and re-install app, even in this case granted automatically

Comment: @HarveyXie https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#EnablingAutoBackup